# Azure Function hangs on error

Tags: node.js, azure, aws-lambda, azure-functions

If you have a error in code and did not callback, Azure Function just hangs.

AWS by default detects for empty loop and exits the lambda and logs the error, return the call to the caller with 5xx. It can also be controlled with callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false.

Is there is anything in Azure Functions that we can control how the function should exist in case of unhandled exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

This currently isn't supported on Azure Functions.

It's the first I've heard this request, but it's a good idea. If you open a GitHub issue for it, I can take a look. (I'm the dev responsible for Node.js on Azure Functions) https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions

Comment: Chris, Should this not be a default expectation of http servers handling code in the backend? Have you seen any http server just hangs the caller in an  exception?

Comment: Functions handles exceptions that propagate to the invoke pipeline, similar to servers likes express.js. Express.js doesn't handle detecting that you didn't call the send/next callback, to my knowledge.

Comment: And, as Nelak, mentioned, if you return a Promise, we'll handle catches/etc. But if you never throw an error that gets to the host and you never call done, we just wait for the timeout.

Comment: That is not what documentation says on expressjs. http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html   Check on catchall error handling that throws 5xx errors.

Comment: And Microsoft thinks leaving it with timeout helps developers to develop in an excellent way with Function App?

Comment: That logic applies if the error propagates to express. If you just forget to call next/etc. because of an error in your code, it does not detect that. What Lambda is doing is looking for your event loop to be empty, and if it is, stopping the execution. It is two very different things to throw an error and have the runtime handle it (which Azure Functions does), and to make a coding error and not call done/next and detect that by looking at the event loop (which we could do, but don't do today). My point was express doesn't do the empty event loop deal today.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Azure Functions beta instead of using callbacks you may also export your functions as async which should allow the node worker to handle the exception without further intervention.
When exporting async functions calling the callback is redundant, and unnecessary.

Example:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    throw new Error('Error')
}
```

Returns:

> Request URL:http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTriggerJS
>
> Request Method:GET
>
> Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
>
> Remote Address:[::1]:7071
>
> Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: Can you please provide an example? I have never done anything like this to get an exception handling in a webapp. Cloud services are meant to be dumb and should be easier to use. Definitely that is not the case here so.

Comment: I've added a simple example to illustrate the function response

Comment: This should work without async, as well. Functions will catch exceptions thrown from a Node.js function as long as the exported function propagates them along.

Comment: Does this also works with asynchronous exceptions as well? `function (context, req) {
    setTimeout(function(){ throw new Error('Error'); } ,0 );
}` . Reference: https://bytearcher.com/articles/why-asynchronous-exceptions-are-uncatchable/

Comment: No, the functions host uses the context for keeping track of the execution of your function or it has no way to address the request. Unless you call done or resolve the promise the function will eventually timeout and your worker will be teared down.

You need to close on the context on the handler for the execution to work. 
If you were to do context.done(new Error) it should work. 
Another option your function returns a promise that calls resolves inside the handler.
You can read a more in depth discussion here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/2117

Comment: Chris Anderson-MSFT
An improvement would be to have the ability to send a 5XX error if certain threshold is exceed per request. You could then use this to troubleshoot long running executions that may tear down your workers, such as forgetting to resolve or not calling context.done properly. This wouldn't avoid the functions host to tearing down the worker but would at least give users some more telemetry

Comment: @nelak Thanks again for response. It is so frustrating to a developer when this basic functionality is not there. With AWS anything I ask for it is available to developer expectations without worrying about infrastructure and just concentrate only on business. Any question I asked with Azure so far returned with a big "NO".  I will share with my developers with your solution and see where it takes. Still not a complete solution though.

Comment: @kannaiyan My feeling is that Azure functions just work, has a really good cli and provide a really good developer experience. Also the nodejs worker is opensource if you want to contribute or better understand what's going on under the hood. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-nodejs-worker
You'll find edge cases as with any other software, Azure functions 2.0 is still in beta but I believe we'll see better documentation, instrumentation and telemetry as other languages move to the new worker architecture.
As Chris suggested open a github issue, they see them and do go through them.

Comment: @nelak I have tested with close to 130+ developers to see how really Azure Function is. Everyone came with a feedback on all the worst words from the dictionary. Still trying to find someone to say Azure Functions made their life easier and concentrate on business rather than how to get the code working.